# Define multiple environment variables in CloudWatch event pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

I am trying to set custom event pattern rule for CloudWatch. What I came up so far is

```
  EventPattern:
    source:
      - aws.codebuild
    detail-type:
      - "CodeBuild Build State Change"
    detail:
      additional-information:
        environment:
          environment-variables:
            name:
              - "ENVIRONMENT"
            value:
              - !Sub "${Environment}"
```

This works fine, however I would like to filter on another environment variable as well. I have already tried with example below, but this does not work.

Example 1: (I can save it , but does not do anything)

```
  EventPattern:
    source:
      - aws.codebuild
    detail-type:
      - "CodeBuild Build State Change"
    detail:
      additional-information:
        environment:
          environment-variables:
            name:
              - "ENVIRONMENT"
              - "MY_ENV"
            value:
              - !Sub "${Environment}"
              - "true"
```

Example 2: (Error: Event pattern contains empty or invalid element (can only be non-empty String, Boolean or Number))

```
  EventPattern:
    source:
      - aws.codebuild
    detail-type:
      - "CodeBuild Build State Change"
    detail:
      additional-information:
        environment:
          environment-variables:
            - name: "ENVIRONMENT"
              value: !Sub "${Environment}"
            - name: "MY_ENV"
              value: "true"
```

Pattern that I get from CodeBuild looks like:

```
{
   "detail":{
      "additional-information":{
         "environment":{
            "environment-variables":[
               {
                  "name":"MY_ENV",
                  "type":"PLAINTEXT",
                  "value":"true"
               },
               {
                  "name":"ENVIRONMENT",
                  "type":"PLAINTEXT",
                  "value":"production"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Any other idea?

Comment: It would be nice if pattern JSON would support something like this: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/r0061295.html